# Plotting categorical variable as stacked bar plot

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization

I have a Pandas dataframe which looks like this:

```
Purpose            LoanStatus  
Business Loan           0  
Business Loan           1  
Buy House               0  
Buy House               1  
Business Loan           1  
Buy a Car               0  
Buy House               0  
Wedding                 1  
Business Loan           0
```

I am trying to make a stacked bar plot with each category being the X-axis and count of 0 and 1 as their two stacks.

How do I do this? do I have to make manual counts for each category or is there a smarter way to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use:

```
pd.crosstab(df['Purpose'], df['LoanStatus']).plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

[image]